# array.filter by object property, argument is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a filter function that takes 2 parameters:
**id type** and the actual **id value**. Using these IDs, I want to filter an array of objects.
For example, here I am trying to get a new array that only includes the values with the name of `'Mike'`.

object:

```
var sample = [
{ name: 'Mike'},
{ name: 'John'}
];
```

filter function:

```
function filterById(obj, parameter, id) {
    return obj.parameter == id;
}
```

this:

```
console.log(sample.filter(filterById(name, 'Mike')));
```

returns name is not defined.

Do I need to pass in the actual array as well? Is it possible to pass parameters into filter functions at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to pass the "parameter" as a string too, and use the square bracket notation, and for this all to work your `filterById` function would *itself* have to return a function which matches the function used by `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var sample = [
  { name: 'Mike'},
  { name: 'John'}
];

function filterById(parameter, id) {
  return function(obj){
    return obj[parameter] == id;
  }
}

console.log(sample.filter(filterById('name', 'Mike')));
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to invoke the function by yourself – it is a [high-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), so you have to provide only function. And here we come to the problem – you want to pass arguments there, but you can't!

So, there are few approaches. The first one is just to return another function, which will keep data in closure:

```
function filterById(parameter, id) {
    return function(item) {
       return item[parameter] == id;
    }
}
```

The second option is to create another function via [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind), which is close to the idea of [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). It will create new function with pre-defined parameters. They are always first, so you have to move actual item definition to the last position:

```
function filterById(parameter, id, item) {
   return item[parameter] === id;
}

// we can create function for the future reference:
const filterByMike = filterById.bind(null, 'name', 'Mike');

sample.filter(filterByMike);
```

It's hard to say what is better, but I'd personally prefer the second approach.